# Origin of "-le-" article in English placenames such as Newton-le-Willows, Bolton-le-Sands, Houghton-le-Spring?

Tags: etymology, french, toponyms

Newton-le-Willows is a town in Merseyside.  Bolton-le-Sands is a village in Lancashire.  Houghton-le-Spring is a town in Tyne and Wear.  There are probably other placenames with -le- in the middle.

What is the origin of these articles?  All appear to be in the North of England, and Anglo-Norman has had [a lot of influence on the English language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Norman_language).  But how did a French article end up in the middle of placenames that do not otherwise exhibit any obvious sign of Frenchness?  Is its origin Norman French at all?

There is a short [reddit thread on the question](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskUK/comments/33hvul/le_in_british_mainly_english_place_names/).  The responses there are not terribly informative, nor is [this digitalspy thread](https://forums.digitalspy.com/discussion/1367103/any-french-place-names-in-the-uk).

Comment: If they're recent, it might be a modern faux-French affectation, kind of like calling shops "shoppe".

Comment: shoppe is old English, not French, though. So, it's not an affectation. It's right in line with the language.

Comment: There is also Chester-le-Street. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chester-le-Street) explains: But "Chester" is a common name for towns in England, and in the Middle Ages "Street", for the Roman road, was added. Also, Hetton-le-Hole. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetton-le-Hole) says: The name of Hetton-le-Hole derives from two Anglo-Saxon words which were spelt together "Heppedune" or Bramble Hill. The name gave rise to a local landowning family, the le Hepdons [...] The ancient manor [..] was divided into two parts known as Hetton-on-the-Hill and Hetton-in-the-Hole.

Comment: Without being able to come up with a specific example to Google I'm fairly certain that this construction (also with *-les-*) is common in French place names

Comment: Slightly different but worth a mention: [Chapel-en-le-Frith](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapel-en-le-Frith)

Comment: @Lambie _Shoppe_ is Middle English, and naming something with a word/form taken from a former, now defunct, variety of a language in order to evoke an old-timey feel is definitely an affectation.

Comment: Shoppe and le have zero to do with each other. Shoppe at least in English, Le is not. Where's the proof about it being affectation??//In French, it's le, la or les. It depends on what follows it. I can find nothing on the internet that explains all the les in English place names. Each seems to have a different origin. Most of the time, there is no explanation on the names even in British History Online, etc.

Comment: Even though shoppe is old English, shop owners might still call it shoppe *believing* it is French, trying to use faux French but in reality using old English ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The main theory for [Houghton-le-Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houghton-le-Spring) is that "le" means "in the"

as evidenced by [The Regester Booke — belonginge to the Paryshe of Houghton in the springe from the yere of our lorde god 1563 vnto this present yere 1598 conteininge, Weddinges, Christninges and Burialles](https://books.google.com/books?id=89oHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22Regester%20Booke%20belonginge%20to%20the%20Paryshe%20of%20Houghton%20in%20the%20Springe%22%20%22burialles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy_YTvyL3TAhUJyyYKHafXD3oQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Regester%20Booke%20belonginge%20to%20the%20Paryshe%20of%20Houghton%20in%20the%20Springe%22%20%22burialles%22&f=false)

Prior to being "Houghton le Spring" it was [Houghton in le Spring](https://books.google.com/books?id=yE5_n6uAiY4C&pg=PA291&dq=%22Houghton%20in%20le%20Spring%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn0rjnyr3TAhXDRiYKHdTNAX0Q6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=%22Houghton%20in%20le%20Spring%22&f=false)

http://www.houghtonlespring.org.uk/main.htm

Comment: Might "le" be related to the old French preposition "lès"? This preposition is used only in place names nowadays. It means "près de" ("near" in English). It is also sometimes written "lez" or "les" (without accent). See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A8s .

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, *some* date back to the 13th century, but others are much later. It will depend on which one you're talking about:

> An interesting example of this is the class of names of the pattern of Chester-le-Street in County Durham. There are at least ten examples of this formation in the one county. For a thousand years from the eighth century Chester was simply *Cestre*, *Cestria*; in 1406 the Latin addition *in Strata* appears, 'on the Roman road', Frenchified as *Chestre in le Strete* in 1411, and simplified to *Chester-le-Street* from 1607. The other nine are [...] Houghton le Spring (*Houghton in le Spryng* 1410-1556) [...]
>
> Elsewhere there are earlier examples: in North Yorkshire, Thornton le Street is *in via* 1208, *in strata* 1268, Thornton le Moor *in mora* 1208, Newton le Willows *in le Wilughes* 1300.
>
> But others are only fifteenth or sixteenth century - Thornton le Beans, *in le Beyns*, *in Fabis* 1534, Barton le Willows, *in the Willos* 1574, Norton le Clay, *in the Clay* 1536...
>
> <sub>[English place-names in the sixteenth century: the search for identity](https://books.google.com/books?id=PKW8PwnSiVMC&pg=PA51)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As children living in N Le Willows we were taught our place name came when. French king commented n Le Willows - because of all the willow trees

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's been theorised by a few English linguists that support the idea that 'Ye' (which is an abbreviation of the word 'the' and is the sound for the but is pronounced 'thee' and not to be confused with 'Thee' meaning 'you') was accidentally corrupted to Le by verbal use. Since there were no grammar police back then spelling was pretty flexible.

To illustrate this better, modern non-scholars and more often than not Americans adopt the 'ye' sounding like the Geordie 'Yee' (meaning You) as the sound to represent the sound in "ye olde house" or 'Yee Oldy Housy" but the 'Ye' is just 'The' and the e in olde is silent, so it's just 'The old house'. It's a bit of an Occam's razor explanation but it removes the whole convoluted french influence which on the surface is quite late after the Norman invasion.

The Roman (and Norse) influence on place names is much more evident than French. So its not conclusive but a town called Chester on ye Street pronounced 'Chester on the Street' could be written as Chester Ye Street but corrupted or corrected by illiterate locals as le instead of the because of the similarity of Ye to yee. If all this sounds a bit weird then it's probably time to take a short trip down the linguistic rabbit hole of old English and check out for yourself the origin of the Ye/The lexography. It doesn't explain how different towns hundreds of miles apart adopted the same convention unless it was unified in some way by a cartographer or by journalists or a convergent evolution in general language usage. Probably a combination of all of the above.

There is no straight forward answer but it's unlikely to be of French origin.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. But I must take issue. *Ye* is not an abbreviation of *the;* it's a corruption of the thorn þ which was used to spell *the, þe.* And if the *-le-* actually derived from *ye,* wouldn't *ye* end up as *y,* "Chester-y-street" because of the pronunciation? Something extra like *l* wouldn't normally be introduced, but *ye* would be reduced to the *ee* sound which can be spelled by retaining *y.* Do you have any citation for *ye* changing to *le*?